# Python - Convert the value of a column from a DataFrame to different columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

See if you can help me, I currently have a JSON file (the content of this file is actually the response of a GET request so I cannot modify it):

```
[
    {
        
        "date": "1620157078",
        "value": "{\"license_plate\": \"1111 AAA\", \"brand\": \"Peugeot\"}"
    },
    {
        "date": "1620157080",
        "value": "{\"license_plate\": \"2222 BBB\", \"brand\": \"Audi\"}"
    }
]
```

And what I'm doing is converting it into a dataframe to be able to work with it in the following way:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
    file_json = json.loads(file)

df = pd.DataFrame(file_json)

df
```

DataFrame content:

```
    date        value
0   1620157078  {"license_plate": "1111 AAA", "brand": "Peugeot"}
1   1620157080  {"license_plate": "2222 BBB", "brand": "Audi"}
```

And what I need is to convert the value of the value field which is a string in more columns, to end up having one like this:

```
    date        license_plate   brand
0   1620157078  1111 AAA        Peugeot
1   1620157080  2222 BBB        Audi
```

I hope you can help me, I have been for almost a whole day trying to make that modification but I have been able. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A built-in and (Pandas-upstream) solution consists of recreating your `file_json`'s dictionaries using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) and [dictionary unpacking](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html).

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> file_json_2 = [{'date': d['date'], **literal_eval(d['value'])} for d in file_json]
```

and then, as you already do

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(file_json_2)
         date license_plate    brand
0  1620157078      1111 AAA  Peugeot
1  1620157080      2222 BBB     Audi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I have a problem executing it:
`---> 10 file_json_2 = [{'date': d['date'], **d['value']} for d in file_json] TypeError: 'str' object is not a mapping`

Comment: @Kevimuxx69 Indeed, I misread your details. Mea culpa. See update. It should work now. As it was, i.e. without using `literal_eval`, it was trying to unpack a string, which is not possible since `'str' object is not a mapping`. `literal_eval` does the conversion-to-dict job prior to unpacking.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the speed

Comment: You are welcome. Actually yours is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your json has `value` field as strings, not dict. You can use `ast.literal_eval` to turn them into dictionaries:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.DataFrame(file_json)

(df.drop('value', axis=1)
   .join(pd.DataFrame(df['value'].apply(literal_eval).to_list()))
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and the speed, it has helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("value").apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         date license_plate    brand
0  1620157078      1111 AAA  Peugeot
1  1620157080      2222 BBB     Audi
```

Comment: Thank you very much really, it works for me. But could you explain to me how you get to that transformation?

Comment: @Kevimuxx69 The `value` key of the dictionary contains another Json string that needs to be parsed. With `.apply(pd.Series)` I expand parsed dictionary to more columns.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much for the explanation, now I understand